# Visual force email template related to issue want to show only last 2 related records

Tags: visualforce, javascript, visualforce-component, email-template

Hi below code shows all case related to account but i want to show only last 3 cases. how can i show these in visual force email template.

```
relatedToType="Account"

subject="Case report for Account: {!relatedTo.name}"

replyTo="support@acme.com">



<messaging:htmlEmailBody>

    <html>



    <body>

        <p>Dear {!recipient.name},</p>

        <table border="0" >

            <tr>

                <th>Case Number</th><th>Origin</th>

                <th>Creator Email</th><th>Status</th>

            </tr>

            <apex:repeat var="cx" value="{!relatedTo.Cases}">

            <tr>

                <td><a href =

                    "https://na1.salesforce.com/{!cx.id}">{!cx.CaseNumber}

                </a></td>

                <td>{!cx.Origin}</td>

                <td>{!cx.Contact.email}</td>

                <td>{!cx.Status}</td>

            </tr>

            </apex:repeat>

        </table>

    </body>

    </html>

</messaging:htmlEmailBody>
```

Please help.

Regards
Russell baker

Comment: One more comment the merge field Recipient.name doesn't work currently it is a known issue. Try putting the related user field..

Answer (score 1):

You can use attribute rows for this

apex:repeat rows=3

In case results are showing in reverse order you can use first attribute to skip and have only last 3

apex:repeat first=(list.size -3)

Update :::

Looks like its hard to get list.size in this context and even if we get ,salesforce may randomly place data into repeater .

Only way i could now think of is using custom components in Visualforce template so that User has access to a controller class and SOQL query to do ordering and limit . Below is the sample from the guide

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_email_templates_with_apex.htm?search_text=email%20templates

Comment: In other cases probably (with a `MAX(list.size - 3, 0)`) but I haven't found a way to get `relatedTo.Cases.size` to compile. (Not sure that the related objects are automatically queried either.)

Comment: Hi Mohith, kudos for you It's working

Comment: which one worked ?

Comment: apex:repeat rows="3"

Comment: Hi Mohit,I afraid to say this but Activities come in reverse order and apex:repeat first=(list.size -3) is showing error. Can you please help me out to pull Activities from last to second last.

Comment: With vf template you can also attach a small controller and we can go via that as code has compile issues

Comment: Hi Mohith ,  This is my class    public  class acctTemplt
{
    public Id accountId {get;set;}
    public List<Opportunity> getopptys()
    {
        List<Opportunity> oppty;
        oppty = [SELECT id, (SELECT ActivityDate,Subject, Status, Description FROM ActivityHistories) FROM Opportunity ORDER BY CreatedDate ASC LIMIT 2];
        return oppty;
    }
}

Comment: This is component but still some thing missing: It asking to create method

Comment: <apex:component controller="acctTemplt" access="global">
    <apex:attribute name="AcctId" type="Id" description="Id of the account" assignTo="{!accountId}"/>
    <table border = "2" cellspacing = "5">
        <tr>
            <td>Opportunity Name</td>
            <td>Opportunity Stage</td>                
        </tr>
        <apex:repeat value="{!opptys.ActivityHistories}" var="cx">
        <tr>
       <tr><td><a href = "https://ap2.salesforce.com/{!cx.id}">View</a></td><td>{!cx.ActivityDate}</td> <td>{!cx.Subject}</td><td>{!cx.Status}</td></tr> </tr> </apex:repeat></table></apex:component>

Comment: Hi Experts,    Is there any one who can help me out.

Comment: Document clearly has instructions what needs to be done..